# Handle AJAX nesting better with promises?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have a nested AJAX call where each level has to wait for the previous one to finish before executing. I am using promises, but I don't see how it can help the below situation.

```
var me = this;

initA()
    .done(function () {
        initB.apply(me, arguments)
            .done(function () {
                initC.apply(me, arguments)
                    .done(function () {
                        initD.apply(me, arguments)
                    });
            });
    });
```

Is there a better way to do this the above nesting?

Comment: Are you using NodeJS or is this in the browser?

Comment: Also, which implementation of promises are you using?

Comment: I'm using this in the browser via jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `then` method and as long as your function returns a promise the promise library will try to resolve the returned promise before moving onto the next `then` callback. With this you can just do a `bind` instead of an `apply`.

In the example below I am using jQuery's deferred objects, but I believe it should be the same for most of the promise libraries

```js
var me = {something:"world"};

function dotimeOut(){
    console.log(this);
    var def = jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
      def.resolve(1);
    },1000);
    return def.promise();
}

dotimeOut()
.then(dotimeOut.bind(me))
.then(dotimeOut.bind(me))
.then(dotimeOut.bind(me));

/* This is the same as doing the below 
    initA()
    .then(function(){
        return initB.apply(me,arguments);
    })
    .then(function(){
        return initC.apply(me,arguments);
    })
    .then(function(){
        return initD.apply(me,arguments);
    }) 
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```